# Orchard CMS - Content Part (Editing) not posting data to server

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I created a new Content Part. I attached the Content Part to a Page Content Item. When editing the Page Content item, the custom Content Part Editor (that I created) shows correctly, having two fields only.

When I fill in data and hit "Save", the Driver's POST Editor action is receiving empty values for the custom part. I am making use of InfoSet in my Part class. However, I am also creating a migration to create a Table for the part record.

Here is some code:

```
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Records;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SlideShare.Models
{
    public class SlideSharePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual string SlideShareId { get; set; }
        public virtual int StartFromSlide { get; set; }
    }

    public class SlideSharePart : ContentPart<SlideSharePartRecord>
    {
        [Required]
        public string SlideShareId
        {
            get { return Retrieve(x => x.SlideShareId); }
            set { Store(x => x.SlideShareId, value); }
        }

        [Required]
        [Range(1,20)]
        public int StartFromSlide
        {
            get { return Retrieve(x => x.StartFromSlide); }
            set { Store(x => x.StartFromSlide, value); }
        }
    }
}

using Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers;
using Orchard.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SlideShare.Models;

namespace SlideShare.Handlers
{
    public class SlideShareHandler : ContentHandler
    {
        public SlideShareHandler(IRepository<SlideSharePartRecord> repository)
        {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
        }
    }
}

using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers;
using SlideShare.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SlideShare.Drivers
{
    public class SlideShareDriver : ContentPartDriver<SlideSharePart>
    {
        protected override string Prefix { get { return "SlideShare"; } }

    protected override DriverResult Display(SlideSharePart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_SlideShare", () => shapeHelper.Parts_SlideShare(
                        SlideShareId: part.SlideShareId,
                        StartsFromSlide: part.StartFromSlide));
    }

    // GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(SlideSharePart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_SlideShare_Edit", () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts.SlideShare",
                Model: part,
                Prfix: Prefix));
    }

    // POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(SlideSharePart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
}

@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model SlideShare.Models.SlideSharePart

<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("SlideShare Presentation Fields")</legend>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SlideShareId, T("SlideShare Id"))
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SlideShareId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SlideShareId)
    </div>
    <div class="hint">@T("Enter the SlideShare Presentation Id")</div>    

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartFromSlide, T("Start From Slide"))
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StartFromSlide)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StartFromSlide)
    </div>
    <div class="hint">@T("Enter the Start From Slide")</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please show the driver and the edit view.

Comment: Hi Bertrand, I had a typo in the Driver, where I used "Prfix" instead of "Prefix". Now it works fine. Thanks